# Bulk get map iteration taking 200 ms

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Map ths = ofy().load().type(Thing.class).ids(123L, 456L, 789L);

I am making this call with 100 ids, RPC call is completing in 100 ms, but to iterate over the result map is taking 200ms, as per the Objectify doc, "this Batch get, asynchrony is hidden behind Map", but if try to iterate the map after 1 sec delay is same.

Answer (score 0):

You can tune the prefetch and fetch size using chunk(), in your case probably chunkAll().